# Excel count if date in one column is within certain range from date in another column

Tags: excel

I've searched all over the Internet for an answer on this and although I've found similar questions, none of them have helped me solve my own little issue:

Let's say I have a two column list, with start dates and end dates - 10 rows so A1:B10. Start dates are in Column A, end dates are in Column B. I want to write a form of CountIf-function (or sumproduct/sumif, whatever gives the required result) that counts only the rows where the start date is more than 365 days earlier than the end date.

The simple way to do this is obviously to make a column C that simply counts the difference by subtracting each start date from each end date, but I want a function that does all the work as I'm going to apply this to a much bigger data set.

Ideally I want the solution to be able to be written as a criteria in a countif, or sumproduct-function as I am working with multiple criterias.

Many many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following array formula (enter with (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=SUM(IF(B1:B10-A1:A10>365,1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you! This unfortunately doesn't seem to work with multiple criteria though, for example if I'd want to find results for between 6 and 12 months I'd try to write: =SUM(IF(AND(B1:B10-A1:A10>183;B1:B10-A1:A10<365);1;0)) and press Ctrl-Shift-Enter, upon which it gives me the answer 0 (despite there being multiple data matching both criteria). Any ideas?

Comment: @DanielSlätt Array formula do not accept `AND()`  replace `AND(B1:B10-A1:A10>183;B1:B10-A1:A10<365)` with `(B1:B10-A1:A10>183)*(B1:B10-A1:A10<365)`

Answer (score 0):

An alternate which does not require array entry:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B10-A1:A10>365))
```